# Using multiple await's in a function, looping, and handling errors

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm struggling to get my head around this. I've searched for similar problems.

Basically, I have 2 asynchronous functions. Let's call them getData() and processData() for the purposes of this question, which both return a promise. (these 2 functions are not defined using the async keyword)

I then have a function which calls these 2 using the async keyword. Like so:

```
async function init() {
    // get the data
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_process.length; i++) {
        try {
            await getData(arr_process[i]);
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }
    }

    // now process the data
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_done.length; i++) {
        try {
            await processData(arr_done[i]);
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is; is this the correct way to handle promise rejections. My understanding is as soon as you define a function using the async keyword it will return a promise. I want to reject that promise if either of the functions using the await keyword (getData or processData) reject a promise - and I don't want the remainder of the function to execute. So if the getData promise rejects above, I don't want the loop to continue or the second loop to start - I want to exit the function returning a rejected promise. Is this the correct implementation of what I'm after? Hopefully that all makes sense!

Comment: You simply need to throw an error when using async await. Just with `throw new Error('failed message')` or in your case `throw err`, or even just remove the entire try catch block and it will be thrown automatically.

Comment: Will that exit out the loop & function ? and return a rejected promise from the init() function?

Comment: Yep, exactly the same as Promise.reject(), just syntax sugar used with `async`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `try`/`catch`es are unnecessary. If a Promise that is `await`ed rejects, the whole containing `async` function will reject, and the rejection value will be the thrown error. You may simply do:

```
async function init() {
    // get the data
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_process.length; i++) {
        await getData(arr_process[i]);
    }
    // now process the data
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_done.length; i++) {
        await processData(arr_done[i]);
    }
}
```

and then, just like with your original code, the caller of `init` will catch any errors with a `catch`:

```
init()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('error:', err);
  });
```

Comment: Unless if OP wants to handle the error, log it and then throw it (though that's pretty much the whole point of having a `Promise#catch` call)

Comment: Ok was unaware the whole containing function would reject. So I assume in your catch above, (err) would be the result of the either getData or processData presuming they were rejected?

Comment: @Alan Right, just like your `return Promise.reject(err);` does, only much less verbose

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an error from within an `async` function by simply using the `throw` keyword.

For example:

```js
async function init() {
  throw new Error('error message')
}
```

or in your case, just remove the try catch blocks and any errors will be thrown automatically.

```js
async function init() {
  // get the data
  for (var i = 0; i < arr_process.length; i++) {
    await getData(arr_process[i]);
  }

  // now process the data
  for (var i = 0; i < arr_done.length; i++) {
    await processData(arr_done[i]);
  }
}
```